# Overload function with null as argument

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that receives a string as argument:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetNames(string name)
{
...
}
```

I want to overload that function to something like this:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetNames(string name = null)
{
...
}
```

But in that case I am getting the following error:

> "Type 'Nameservice' already defines a member called 'GetNames' with the same types".

How can I overload this method properly to be used when argument is null.

Comment: String is a reference type and always nullable

Comment: the second example shows an optional parameter. You cannot overload it. Do you intend to have a different implementation for the 2 examples that you show? and if yes, then what exactly would be the difference?

Comment: @NTINNEV I don't really understand you comment. Why is this relevant?

Comment: @MongZhu yes, in first one when name is not null I am getting some data from DB for that Name and then compare some data againts the name. If name is null I don't do that

Comment: @MongZhu "Type 'Nameservice' already defines a member called 'GetNames' with the same types". Because String is always nullable these 2 methods are exactly the same.

Comment: @NTINNEV "Because String is always nullable these 2 methods are exactly the same." Not exactly. They are the same, because the signature which consists of the name and the parameter set is the same. Making the parameter optional by giving a default value does not change the parameter set, irrespective of the point whether it is nullable or not. You would get the same error message for an int parameter: `void Method( int a)` and `void Method( int a = 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I overload this method properly to be used when argument is null.

An overload aims to provide a method with the same name but a different parameter set. It is not meant to make an assertion about the values of the parameter. If you want to do that you would need to do it inside the method and in this case call another method

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetNames(string name)
{
    if(name is null)
    {
        return await GetNames();
    }
    else
    {
        // use "name"
    }
}


public async Task<List<string>> GetNames()
{
    // do something different
}
```

for clarification:

> GetNames(string name = null)

this is not an overload, because the parameter set remains the same. This makes the parameter optional! so that it is not needed anymore at the calling site.

Comment: Suggesting `if(name is null)` instead of `if(name == null)`

Comment: @Fildor suggestion implemented. Why exactly is it nicer?

Comment: "==" operator _could_ potentially be overloaded. "is" is the safer alternative.